# Arch Linux failed to install libproxy for invalid signature

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

The following message is from my terminal:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (1): libproxy-0.4.7-2

Total Installed Size:   0.29 MiB

Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                        

[###############################################] 100%
error: libproxy: signature from "Evangelos Foutras<evangelos@foutrelis.com>"  is invalid
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Always start your installation with `-Syu`, in this case, you probably used an old `arch-keyring` package.

Just do `pacman -Syu archlinux-keyring` first, and try the installation of libproxy afterwards

Anyway a quick dirty hack is put a line `SigLevel = Never` in /etc/pacman.conf (under the `[options]` label, or modify existing one) to bypass this restriction temporarily.

Comment: still failed . Is that "install with -Syu " not means "upgrade the whole system "? I just wanna install single package .

Comment: @cdh try the dirty hack then, and remove that afterwards; and `-Syu` means upgrade whole system yes, but in this case, it means upgrade whole system while install the desired package

Comment: Added `SigLevel = Never`  ,still not worked .

Comment: @cdh updated the answer, I wasn't clear on that part

Comment: For me the `sudo pacman -Syu archlinux-keyring` was the solution. Thank you

Comment: `pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring` was the solution for me....Didn't want to do a full upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `pacman` isn't checking the right key... Indeed, the `libproxy` package is not signed by [Evangelos Foutras](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=&maintainer=foutrelis&flagged=), but by [Jan de Groot](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=&maintainer=jgc&flagged=). Maybe E.F. was the previous maintainer, and your `pacman` hasn't acknowledged the change.

You might want to download a fresh copy of the master package list first:

```
$ pacman -Syyu
```

- `-S`: Synchronise packages.
- `-yy`: Refresh the master package list (twice to ignore *"already up-to-date"* cases).
- `-u`: System upgrade.

Even though you're trying to install 1 package in particular, keeping your system (and `pacman`) up-to-date is essential. Make sure this command exits successfully and try to install your package again.

Adding `SigLevel = Never` to `pacman`'s configuration ([see warl0ck's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57290/41892)) will allow you to bypass all these checks.