# Arch Linux steam installation failed due to signature error

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, signature

I'm trying to install steam on my Arch and pacman said it can't install and showed
the following error

```
error: steam: signature from "Daniel Wallace <danielwallace@gtmanfred.com>" is invalid
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I also did

```
pacman -Syu archlinux-keyring
```

as suggested in 
[Arch Linux failed to install libproxy for invalid signature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57289/archlinux-failed-to-install-libproxy-for-invalid-signature)

Comment: Delete the package from your cache manually and `pacman -Syyu steam`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been answered in the comments:

> Delete the package from your cache manually and pacman -Syyu steam... – jasonwryan

.

> yeah, that worked.. Thanks – pahnin